# Dynamic sql query input and output values pass into variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It is an sample where the number of columns are variables. I am doing that but in @VigenciaHastaValor I have a null.

```
DECLARE @VigenciaHastaValor NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @VigenciaHasta NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @VigenciaHasta = N'SELECT'+ @VigenciaHastaValor+' = [2]
       FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY SECMAX) AS Row 
     ,[2]
      ,[3]
      ,[4]
      ,[5]
    FROM [interurbano].[dbo].[sonpruebas]) AS EMP
WHERE Row = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM [interurbano].[dbo].[sonpruebas] ) PRINT(@VigenciaHastaValor)'



 EXEC sp_executesql @VigenciaHasta,N'@name NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT',
        @VigenciaHastaValor OUTPUT
 PRINT(@VigenciaHastaValor)
```

Comment: I can't see `@name` in your dynamic SQL....

Comment: Please check your query result.  It will be null when there are no  records satisfying the condition!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I find the solution doing this

```
DECLARE @VigenciaHastaValor NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @VigenciaHasta NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @VigenciaHasta = N'SELECT @name = [2]
       FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY SECMAX) AS Row 
     ,[2]
      ,[3]
      ,[4]
      ,[5]
    FROM [interurbano].[dbo].[sonpruebas]) AS EMP
WHERE Row = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM [interurbano].[dbo].[sonpruebas] ) '



 EXEC sp_executesql @VigenciaHasta,N'@name NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT',
        @VigenciaHastaValor OUTPUT
```